# How to sum each row and make other operations with each of the final value in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to get the sum of the bottles in each row and multiple the sum with the price ($2) and subtract a discount ($0.50) every time the sum reaches a multiple of 3 using:

```
={"Total Price";arrayformula(if(len(B2:B),mmult(n(B2:D),transpose(sign(column(B1:D1)))),))}
```

Is there a way to do it?

[image]

Comment: So in your example, would the discounted price be $4.50 ($0.50 off each bottle) or $5.50 ($0.50 off the normal total price of $6) ?

Comment: its the $5.50 one

Comment: $6 "reaches a multiple of 3" twice. 2 x 0.50 = 1. So wouldn't the price of three bottles (3 x $2.00) be reduced to $5.00, not $5.50?

Comment: oh sorry, I am was referring to the sum of bottles reaching multiples of 3 not the price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try expanding your formula to compute the discounted price:

Assume x = `mmult(n(B2:D),transpose(sign(column(B1:D1)))`, your computation will be:

`2*x - floor(x/3)/2`

And your expanded formula will be:

```
={"Total Price";arrayformula(if(len(B2:B),2*mmult(n(B2:D),transpose(sign(column(B1:D1))))-floor(mmult(n(B2:D),transpose(sign(column(B1:D1))))/3)/2,))}
```

**Sample Output:**

[image]

Comment: Let me know if I interpreted your formula correctly or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that this is really a math question. That said, as I understand your goal, try this in F1:

`={"Total Price";arrayformula(if(len(B2:B),(mmult(n(B2:D),transpose(sign(column(B1:D1))))*2)-(int((mmult(n(B2:D),transpose(sign(column(B1:D1))))*2)/3)*0.5),))}`